# Updating Model from the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am confused about how to update my viewmodel in MVC3.  What I am trying to do on a button click search my viewmodel for a particular list item.  Example:

```
BooksViewModel

public List<Book> Books{get;set;}
```

In my view when the user clicks on a button I need to search the List in the ViewModel like this:

```
Controller
public void SetContent(int chapterId, int paragraphId)
{
  var paragraph = booksViewModel.Books.Where(b =>b.ChapterId == chapterId).First().Chapter.Paragraphs.Where(p => p.Id == paragraphId).First()
  model.CurrentParagraph = paragraph;
}
```

The problem I am having is that I cant access the instance of the BooksViewModel from the controller.  How do I access the instance of the viewmodel that the view is using that already has the data which was retrieved from the database?  Or am i going about this all wrong?

THanks in advance

**edit**

maxim suggested passing in my model from the view to the secondary call to the controller (i.e. to filter the model)

would i do that by using the     @Model keyword like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Books/SetSelectedContent?id=" + id + "&paragraphId="+paragraphId+"&model="+@Model, // the URL of the controller action method
            data: null, // optional data
            success: function(result) {

            },
            error: function(req, status, error) {
                alert('error' + error);
            }
        });
```

When I tried this it seemed the ajax call choked on @Model

Comment: Yeah, that'll choke - can't just append the entire model to the url like that.  It doesn't know how to translate that into a url encoded string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the web and views are stateless.  Once the action is executed, it's gone (unless you session things, but that's a different beast).

If you want to search the list after it's been passed to the view, in a different controller action (brand new request, everything from the previous request is gone), then you'll have to recreate the list.

```
public MyController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var books = _service.GetBooks();
        return View(new BooksViewModel
        {
            Books = books
        });
    }

    // Once the button is clicked, it routes to this action:
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SetSelectedContent(int paragraphId)
    {
        // Here you search for the specific paragraph that you want.
        // Ideally this goes in a service call, but here to illustrate.
        // The linq query won't materialize every book, but will give an
        // optimized query that only gives the paragraph that you want.
        // Depending on your model structure, this will work better.

        // Paragraph Id's should be unique, yes? so no need for the chapter
        // then.
        var paragraph = database.Paragraphs
            .Single(p => p.paragraphId == paragraphId);

        // Note the 'Content' here, not View.  This will return just the
        // plain text to be replaced by ajax.
        return Content(paragraph);
    }
}
```

Here's the fix for that ajax sample:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Books/SetSelectedContent",

        // populate the data with whatever the chapter and paragraph id should be.
        data: { pargraphId: @paragraphId }
        success: function(result) {
            // Here you do something with the result.
            // This would just replace a specific div with the contents
            // of the searched paragraph.
            $('#DivToReplace').html(result);
        },
        error: function(req, status, error) {
            alert('error' + error);
        }
    });
```

Again, the SetSelectedContent should be able to just filter the database by the params - it shouldn't have to actually materialize the entire table of books, so sessioning or caching just adds an extra layer of complexity.

Comment: thank for this.  While this does help me understand that the web is stateless and i cant access the viewmodel from index anymore, I really dont want to call _service.GetBooks again.  maybe the solution is really to implement some caching in _service.

Comment: A better question to ask here is what exactly you're doing with IEnumerable<Book>?  Are you displaying entire books at once?  Are you just displaying a list of book names?  What exactly are you doing with the data that makes it so expensive to pull again for each request? There are ways you can trim down what you're pulling out of the database here.

Comment: In the same view i am displaying verses from the book, and giving users the ability to add comments on a particular verse/paragraph, hide or show comments all which are stored in the iEnumerable<Book> list that is stored in the model

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense.  So IEnumerable<Book> isn't actually, as the name would imply, a list of books, but a list of verses from a single book.  Either way, look at pulling comments and paragraphs via Ajax.  You shouldn't have to deal with the sessioning or cache at all.  The database search for a paragraph doesn't need to materialize every book, just the single filtered paragraph. I took the session stuff out of my answer.

Comment: Cleaned up my answer to show just the ajax action that gets called.  It would have been helpful to actually see what your models looked like, so I guessed a bit.

Comment: Thanks this helps. My solution is actually very similar to what you came up with here.  Thanks for the assistance and such a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

When you send a View to a user browser, you create an instance of your Model (in your case you call it ViewModel). This is done as a part of some Action that returns a view in your Controller.  If you want a modified version of you Model to be reconstructed for Action-procession, you should request it as a parameter in you Action's signature in case of a form `POST` submit, or you just create a new Model and initialize View with it.

From what I see, this is the case. Just create a new `BooksViewModel`, do a filtering and send a  `View(myFilteredModel)` to a user.

But you can also try this:

```
[HttpPost]    
public void SetContent(int chapterId, int paragraphId, BooksViewModel booksViewModel)
    {
      var paragraph = booksViewModel.Books.Where(b =>b.ChapterId == chapterId).First().Chapter.Paragraphs.Where(p => p.Id == paragraphId).First()
      model.CurrentParagraph = paragraph;
    }
```

As for DB-access per action execution - this is solved via implementing a cache mechanism.

Comment: Yes in my controller method that creates the view I send the model to the view but how do i access that same model in future calls to controller methods

Comment: I could do that but that would mean I have make a call to the database and repopulate all the "Books" in the new instance of BooksViewModel.  I would like to avoid making this extra database call as it could be returning a large amount of data.

Comment: That same model - only if you post it back to the server. You access a desired parameters `int chapterId, int paragraphId` and just create a new one. If you want an ajax-way of just doing a filter - you need to initialize an ajax call to your action from javascript, and based on the response just update the page. Moving to a different action means you are moving away from the view.

Comment: Check out my updated answer with POSTing a model to an action.

Comment: please see my update on the question addressing your suggestion.  Thank you

Comment: No, you post just chapterId and paragraphId, get the filtered response (making a db call via some DB provider) and update your view (html page) with data received in success: handler.